# File Transfer to another iOS device using Bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, file-transfer

Is there a way to programmatically send a file from one iOS device to another using bluetooth. I have used Air Drop but I can't seem to find a proper code snippet for bluetooth file transfer in iOS .

Comment: https://github.com/unixpickle/ImageTransfer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use iOS7 MultipeerConnectivity.framework to transfer file using bluetooth and wifi. Check the apple sample code https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MultipeerGroupChat/Introduction/Intro.html and grap the file transfer code.